# How do I center a header both vertically and horizontally in CSS?

Tags: html, css

```
 <html>
  <head>
  <h1>Hello.</h1>
  </head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="butters.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Galada" rel="stylesheet">
  <body></body>
</html>
```

+

```
h1{
   font-family: 'Galada', cursive;
   font-size: 400%;
   position: relative;
   top: 50%;
   left: 50%;
   transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

[Link to fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/6oyq0szs/)
[I pretty much followed this tutorial.](http://zerosixthree.se/vertical-align-anything-with-just-3-lines-of-css/)

I'm finding issues with it though because it creates a horizontal scroll bar, which I don't want and I don't believe it is centering horizontally. I just want it to be smack dab in the middle of the screen no matter the screen size but i'm not sure what CSS it'll take to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed your CSS:

```
h1{
   font-family: 'Galada', cursive;
   font-size: 70px;
   transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
   position: absolute;
   top: calc(50% - 35px);
   left: 50%;   
}
```

Comment: Thanks! [It pretty much works now](https://jsfiddle.net/6oyq0szs/1/) but it appears that there's more top space than bottom space despite the 50%. Do you see that too or am I just delusional?

Comment: Yep, you're right. It happens because the top of the element is what effectivelly is centered. I changed the CSS to specify the `font-size` in pixels and the `top` calculated with the half of font-size as discount.

Answer (score 0):

try changing position:relative to position:absolute

Answer (score 0):

Two things - firstly, you have an h1 in your head, which is invalid, you'll want to move that to your body. From there, you need to give the body positioning for that 50% to be in reference to. It'll also need to get position:absolute for left and top to work properly. After that, you can do both a translateX and translateY to get it centered on both axis. Example below!

```
h1{
   font-family: 'Galada', cursive;
   font-size: 400%;
   position: absolute;
   top: 50%;
   left: 50%;
   transform: translateY(-50%) translateX(-50%);
}
body{
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/will0220/pw4j2m36/1/

Answer (score 0):

H1 should be in the BODY. It's not a valid HEAD element.

Vertical centering depends on height of the container too.

Use:

```
html,body {
 height:100%;
}
```

http://www.codeply.com/go/u9kxrMCzK8

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace *top* by *margin-top* for relative elements:

```css
h1{
   font-family: 'Galada', cursive;
   font-size: 400%;
   position: relative;
   margin-top: 50%;
   left: 50%;
   transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
  <h1>Hello.</h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
The easiest way to align text horizontally is "text-align: center", if You know vertical height, You can align vertically with "line-height: (value)px"

HTML
<body>
    <h1>Hello.</h1>
</body>

CSS
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

h1 {
  font-family: 'Galada', cursive;
  font-size: 400%;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 50%;
}
```